# Hylleraas Multi-dimensional integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration

> Evaluate the hylleraas integral 
>   $$\int \int \frac{\exp(-ar_{1}-br_{2}-cr_{12})}{r_{1}r_{2}r_{12}}d^{n}r_{1}d^{n}r_{2} $$
>   with $r_{1}=|\vec{r_{1}}|$, $r_{2}=|\vec{r_{2}}|$, $r_{12}=|\vec{r_{2}}-\vec{r_{1}}|$ for $n = 3$, and general $n$.

I've managed to solve for the $n=3$ case taking two different paths. Through fourier transforms and through a transformation of the volume element in spherical coordinates 
$d^{3}r_{1}d^{3}r_{2}$ to $$d^{3}r_{1}d^{3}r_{12}=r_{1}^{2}sin^{2}(\theta)dr_{1}d\theta d\phi r_{12}^{2}sin(\xi)dr_{12}d\xi d{\psi}$$

and the cosine relation $$r^{2}_{2}=r_{1}^{2}+r_{12}^2-2r_{1}r_{12}cos(\xi)$$ where $$r_{2}dr_{2}= r_{1}r_{12}sin(\xi)d\xi.$$

My problem is that I don't know, how to solve this in n dimensions. If I use the same trick with the cosine, I arrive to a integral with some ugly incomplete gamma functions multiplied with exponentials. If i want to try to use the fourier transform method i would need to know a fourier transform in n dimensions that leads me to $\frac{exp(-cr_{12})}{r_{12}}$. I hope somebody give me some help with this, I would appreciate a lot.

Comment: Wouldn't Mathematics SE be a better place to post this question?

Comment: Welcome on the PSE! I think you might have more luck on the https://math.stackexchange.com .